# jQuery serialize() not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, laravel

I have an HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="create_user" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <span>Username</span><input required="true" type="text" name="username" id="username">

    <span>E-mail</span><input type="email" name="email" id="email">

    <span>Privileges</span><select id="role" name="role"><option value="1">Administrator</option><option value="2">Employee</option><option value="3">Dealer</option></select>

    <span>Password</span><input type="password" name="password" id="password">

    <span>Repeat Password</span><input type="password" name="repeat_password" id="repat_password">

    <input class="btn-primary btn" type="submit" value="Submit">

    <input class="btn-inverse btn" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I'm trying to send the data to the server using AJAX, like such:

```
$("form").submit(function(){

            var form_data = $(this).serialize();

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "user/validate",
                type: "POST",
                data: form_data 
            });
            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert(response);//Comes back blank
            })
            // callback handler that will be called on failure
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // log the error to the console
                console.error(
                    "The following error occured: "+
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );
            });
        });
```

Edit: Here is my Laravel controller that handles the POST data:

```
class User_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function post_validate() {
        return Input::get('username');
    }

}
```

However, no data is sent using `$(this).serialize()`. If I individually pass each element by doing something like this: `$("#username").val()`, it works fine. I made sure all my form inputs had names, however it still didn't work.

Comment: Works fine in a stripped down jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yMUc9/

Comment: if `response` is blank, your `user/validate` page isn't returning anything. Look at your server-side script for problems.

Comment: @KevinB `user/validate` works fine when I pass data like this: `data: { "username" : username.val() }`, so I don't think it's an issue with the page.

Comment: It has to be. If you are getting to the success callback, that means your server script was accessed and returned nothing. Are you targeting the correct form?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Is the request/response as expected?

Comment: What does $_POST contain in your user/validate file?

Comment: My `user/validate` is a very simple Laravel controller for testing this. All it does is this: `return Input::get('username');`

Comment: Have you tried stopping it from refershing like a another person suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I think your page get refreshed:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); //<-----try adding this
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it and I don't believe your problem is in serialising the data.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6nd5K/

You should test by checking if serialise does anything *before* it goes in your AJAX method.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

I think your problem lies in whatever processes the data.

Comment: How do you figure? The `Input::get()` handles GET and POST data

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn-primary").on(click, function(){

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/user/validate",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form#create_user').serialize(),
            async: false

        });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert(response);//Comes back blank
        })
        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });
    });
```